# How to access the application from other device in local network

Tags: networking, proxy, localhost, port, hosts

In the project I am working on, there is an application that works on many docker containers. To access one of the containers I need to add the following path in the */etc/hosts* file

```
127.0.0.1 my.domain.com
```

Then App of course is available on http://my.domain.com in my computer.
Unfortunately, This is large complicated application and I cannot change the configuration to add a port (then i would use 192.168.X.X:PORT from other device)? so **How I would to be able to access the application from other device in local network** (WIFI or other way)? I try using localtunnel or ngrok but this works too slow and aren't good in this case.

Maybe someone knows another way?

Comment: Could you give an example of expected behaviour on "other device" to access your endpoint?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? 1. Your app is not available in lan by ip address? 2. Your app requires exact domain name and rejects requests with other names? 3. Both problems. 4. Something different

Comment: I just want to serve app from my machine that works on some.domain.com (in docker) to other device in local network. If you know that if App works on e.g. localhost:8000 then I can open this site from my other device in local network by use local IP like 192.168.0.100:8000. But in this situation i don't have available port and can't use it.

Comment: Default port is 80. When you open http://my.domain.com browser uses port 80, it can't be without the port (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Port). The problem you have is that your app listens only on the address 127.0.0.1 (which is a special address available from localhost only) as I can imagine, but not on a network interface. Please provide you docker run / compose commands for more info and read this doc: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: When I try 192.168.0.100:80 i receive 502 bad gateway, but other service from port 3000 on docker works.

Comment: One of container is a gateway and in PORTS has ```0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5432```, and one of front app (that i want to access) has port ```9000-9001/tcp```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241720/discussion-between-oleg-flores-and-januszo).

Answer (score 0):

If your server is running on ip `192.168.X.X` on you local network, adding the line:

```
192.168.X.X my.domain.com
```

to the second device on your network should do the job

Another solution is to run a proxy server on the same instance as your server and send all the requests to the proxy server. The proxy server will listen on another port but it will forward all the requests to `my.domain.com` with the original port, it will work since it uses the same `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: interfering with hosts on another device is not a solution. You will not do this on your phone

Comment: I would do it for a laptop when testing stuff on LAN

Comment: Maybe you can take another aproach. I have an application which requires exact host, like yours, In python django it's called ALLOWED_HOSTS. I change my app to allow all hosts when running locally or on LAN.

Comment: some e.g. of proxy server? I try to use nginx proxy reverse but without success.

Comment: I would use nginx, there are alternatives but all of them require some development to config according to your setup. I guess the most popular are: nginx, HaProxy, envoy, apache.

Answer (score 0):

try using nginx-webserver proxy it's free version it offers the feature what you want.

add a reverse proxy and host your app with `my.domain.com`

**OR**

Host your app on port `:80` ie. the default port

Comment: what you mean by nginx-webserver?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).